# vim loses linebreak setting in insert mode, returns it in normal mode

Tags: vim

I'm working with long lines of prose. My .vimrc has "set linebreak" and so forth to make lines wrap reasonably, and it's working fine in normal mode, but when I go into insert and begin editing, the line abruptly switches to wrapping at the window width, not word boundaries. When I go back to normal mode, it reverts to wrapping the way I want. It's annoying and distracting.

This is a new development, but I can't figure out what change I could have made to cause this.

Comment: What version is this?

Comment: in .vimrc `set wm=1`  will produce a comfortable way of automatically  insert newlines in insert mode without breaking words.

Comment: This is still going on, but I've narrowed it down. Using "i" to go into insert mode will not cause it, but using "cw" or "c" in visual mode will. The version is 7.4.

Comment: Looks like it's this: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/312